# when i want to run a networkshare in tcl script file i got System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found

Tags: tcl

i have an issue when i try to use ( in TCL script file ) :

set res [exec cmd.exe /c "net use //server/share" &];

i got a windows issue : System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you type the same `net use //server/share` on the Windows command line, does that succeed?

Comment: Hello Colin Macleod , yes of course , its works on command line but i get that error when i run it with a tcl software : xxxxx.exe -t C:\folder\file.tcl

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you don't need to go through cmd.exe, also it doesn't help to run this in the background, and you need to put the network name in windows format, so I would just do:

```
set res [exec net use \\\\server\\share]
```

Comment: Or `{\\server\share}` to avoid all the doubled up backslashes.

Comment: when i run it in a software that supports tcl files only 
it does not works showing this error :
invalid command name "net"
    while executing
"unknown_original net use {\ip\share}"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval unknown_original $cmd $args"
    (procedure "::unknown" line 7)
    invoked from within
"net use \\ip\share"
    invoked from within
"set res [ net use \\ip\share]"
    (file "C:\folder\file.tcl" line 1)

Comment: i have write ( set res [net use \\\\server\\share] ) in a tcl file , it works in a tcl software without errors but i didnt get a response from my  \\server\\share to prove that \\server\\share was executed

Comment: Sorry, I left out `exec` but it is needed, I added it now.

Comment: Would `file nativename` help here? (I'm on the wrong platform to test…)